# Does a virtual function has to be void?

Tags: c++, class, polymorphism

I want to know if a virtual function, used for polymorphism, can return something like an int, instead of being a void. For example, can a getter be virtual?

Example:

```
class Person{
int number;
public:
...
  virtual int get_number(){return number}
};
```

Comment: Yes virtual functions can return values.

Comment: Out of interest, why did you think it needed to be void?

Comment: You forgot the semicolon (`;`) after `return number`.

Comment: Did you dare confront your compiler with that audacious attempt? Would you be inclined to share the error message, if any, with your rapt audience? As a general rule, we appreciate the following here: (1) A clear problem. Check. (2) Source code. Check. (3) *Any and all output from the compiler and linker, and, if the program compiled and linked, its output.* MIssing. We also are happy about own research before posting here, although we tend not to learn about people who do.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Here is a code example where we have used the virtual function `getType()`. [Source](https://www.programiz.com/cpp-programming/virtual-functions)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Animal {
   private:
    string type;

   public:
    // constructor to initialize type
    Animal() : type("Animal") {}

    // declare virtual function
    virtual string getType() {
        return type;
    }
};

class Dog : public Animal {
   private:
    string type;

   public:
    // constructor to initialize type
    Dog() : type("Dog") {}

    string getType() override {
        return type;
    }
};

class Cat : public Animal {
   private:
    string type;

   public:
    // constructor to initialize type
    Cat() : type("Cat") {}

    string getType() override {
        return type;
    }
};

void print(Animal* ani) {
    cout << "Animal: " << ani->getType() << endl;
}

int main() {
    Animal* animal1 = new Animal();
    Animal* dog1 = new Dog();
    Animal* cat1 = new Cat();

    print(animal1);
    print(dog1);
    print(cat1);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: your example is a bit weird because you didn't need a virtual function here.

Answer (score 1):

Yes virtual function used for polymorphism can return any type, instead of being a void.
Refer the code below.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
using namespace std;

class Person {
    int age1 = 24;
public:
    virtual int get_number() 
    { 
        return age1;
    }
};

class Developer : Person
{
    int age2 = 35;
public:
    int get_number()
    {
        return age2;
    }
};

void main()
{
    Person *p = new Person();
    Developer *p2 = new Developer();

    cout << p->get_number() << endl;
    cout << p2->get_number() << endl;

    _getch();
}
```

OUTPUT:
24
35